# Equivalent of nvalue/2 from SICStus in SWIProlog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd, sicstus-prolog

The [SICStus](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.0.5/html/sicstus/Combinatorial-Constraints.html) manual for the CLP(FD) library says:

> **`nvalue(?N, +Variables)`** where `Variables` is a list of domain variables with finite bounds or integers, and `N` is an integer or a
>   domain variable. True if `N` is the number of distinct values taken by
>   `Variables`.

This is particularly useful when one wants to minimize the number of distinct values in the solution. For example, if one is trying to distribute stuff into bags of different sizes, and want to minimize the number of bags.

Is there an equivalent predicate (or way) for achieving the same in SWI Prolog?

Comment: Is that what [`fd_size/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=fd_size/2) does?

Comment: I don't think so... `fd_size/2` returns the number of elements of a domain. For example, `X in 0..10, fd_size(X, 11)`. I'm looking for something that constrains the number of *distinct* elements in a list of variables.

Comment: And you would expect `X in 0..10, foo([X], 1)`?

Comment: I would expect `length(Vs, 3), Vs ins 1..3, nvalue(2, Vs)` to exclude as possible answers things like `Vs = [3, 3, 3]` or `Vs = [1, 2, 3]`, because we are saying that there must be two distinct values.

Comment: [Backlink](https://github.com/triska/clpz/issues/8) to improvements in clpz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After @jschimpf comment, I've rethought the algorithm.

```
nvalue(1, [_]).
nvalue(C, [V|Vs]) :-
    count_equals(V, Vs, E),
    E #= 0 #/\ C #= R+1 #\/ E #> 0 #/\ C #= R,
    nvalue(R, Vs).

count_equals(_, [], 0).
count_equals(V, [U|Vs], E) :-
    V #= U #/\ E #= E1+1 #\/ V #\= U #/\ E #= E1,
    count_equals(V, Vs, E1).
```

*further cleanup*

again, after @jschimpf note, I've tweaked the code: now it's very compact, thanks to libraries apply and yall.

```
nvalue(1, [_]).
nvalue(C, [V|Vs]) :-
    maplist({V}/[U,Eq]>>(Eq#<==>V#=U), Vs, Es),
    sum(Es, #=, E),
    E #= 0 #/\ C #= R+1 #\/ E #> 0 #/\ C #= R,
    nvalue(R, Vs).
```

*old answer, buggy*

my naive attempt, based on [reification](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%23%3C%3D%3D%3E/2):

```
% nvalue(?N, +Variables)
nvalue(N, Vs) :-
    nvalues(Vs, [], VRs),
    sum(VRs, #=, N).

nvalues([], Acc, Acc).
nvalues([V|Vs], Acc, VRs) :-
    nvalues_(V, Vs, Acc, Upd),
    nvalues(Vs, Upd, VRs).

nvalues_(_V, [], Acc, Acc).
nvalues_(V, [U|Vs], Acc, Upd) :-
    V #\= U #<==> D,
    nvalues_(V, Vs, [D|Acc], Upd).
```

running your example query:

```
?- length(Vs, 3), Vs ins 1..3, nvalue(2, Vs), label(Vs).
Vs = [1, 1, 2] ;
Vs = [1, 1, 3] ;
Vs = [1, 2, 1] ;
Vs = [1, 2, 2] ;
Vs = [1, 3, 1] ;
Vs = [1, 3, 3] ;
Vs = [2, 1, 1] ;
Vs = [2, 1, 2] ;
Vs = [2, 2, 1] ;
Vs = [2, 2, 3] ;
Vs = [2, 3, 2] ;
Vs = [2, 3, 3] ;
Vs = [3, 1, 1] ;
Vs = [3, 1, 3] ;
Vs = [3, 2, 2] ;
Vs = [3, 2, 3] ;
Vs = [3, 3, 1] ;
Vs = [3, 3, 2].
```

*edit*

my code was a bit pedantic, of course could be more compact (and clear ?):

```
nvalue(N, Vs) :-
    bagof(D, X^H^T^V^(append(X, [H|T], Vs), member(V, T), V #\= H #<==> D), VRs),
    sum(VRs, #=, N).
```

note that findall/3 will not work, since the copy of reified variable D would lose the posted constraints.

Comment: Not correct: your code succeeds for `nvalue(3, [1,1,1,2])`, for example.

Comment: Nice rewrite! Note that you can still simplify by turning the summation in `count_equals/3` into a conjunction using `E#<==>E1#/\(V#\=U)`, and simply summing the resulting booleans in the outer loop.

Comment: @jschimpf: thanks again. I've followed your hint, but simplified... hope I got it right ... at least, it seems ok.

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind. You don't need to compute the sum `E` of the satisfied equalities, you only have to compute a boolean `D` that is true if all equalities are false. Then you can simplify `E #= 0 #/\ C #= R+1 #\/ E #> 0 #/\ C #= R` to `C #= R+D`.